# How to get all links from frame using JS

Tags: javascript, frames, frameset

I have code for get all frames on page:

```
var framesets = document.getElementsByTagName('frameset');
for (var i = 0; i < framesets.length; i++) {
  console.log(framesets[i])
}
```

I want get links from frame. Over document I can execute `document..getElementsByTagName('a')`, but how to use over frame?

`framesets[i].getElementsByTagName('a')` not working.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Can you post here the output of `console.log(framesets[0])` ... that would help understand what are you working with

Comment: If the frame is not pointed to a location on the same origin as your page you won't be able to access its contents as it is considered a security hazard if it was allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `window.frames[i].document.getElementsByTagName('a');`

Comment: Document over `framesets[i]` is undefined

Comment: Try out my edit please :)